# Double for loops for print

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I only have one list

list<- c("hello", "my", "name", "is", "micky",".")

How do I do a secondary loop inside the code I already have?

```
for(i in 1:12){
  print(c[i])
}
```

What I am looking for is to print the output as:

```
hello
hello my
hello my name
hello my name is
hello my name is micky
hello my name is micky.
```

Comment: You need `for(i in seq_along(list)) print(list[1:i])` or may be `for(i in seq_along(list)) cat(paste(list[1:i], collapse=" "), sep="\n")`

Comment: BTW, a similar quesiton you posted some time back

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
vec<- c("hello", "my", "name", "is", "micky",".")

for(i in 1:length(vec)){
   for(j in 1:i) {
    cat(vec[j], " ")
   }
  cat("\n")
}

#hello  
#hello  my  
#hello  my  name  
#hello  my  name  is  
#hello  my  name  is  micky  
#hello  my  name  is  micky  .
```

However, you can also do

```
sapply(seq_along(vec), function(x) paste0(vec[1:x], collapse = " "))

#[1] "hello"           "hello my"         "hello my name"           
#[4] "hello my name is"  "hello my name is micky"   "hello my name is micky ."
```